Use Cloudflare proxy with Firebase App Hosting
I'm using Firebase App Hosting to host my Nextjs app. However, it seems TTFB and  performance is not optimal, resulting in bad core web vital scores and overall bad user experience due to slow loading times.
As mentioned in Firebase App Hosting Cache-Control (NextJS) and https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-hosting/about-app-hosting, there seems to be a CDN in place, but it's always a MISS for me.
Therefore I want to use Cloudflare proxy to have a proper CDN in place.
However I'm not able to enable the Cloudflare proxy, since App Hosting domain connection will switch from "Completed" to "Needs setup" and then breaks.
Yesterday it worked for a few minutes before going back to "Needs setup", and it worked perfectly with TTFB of 0.1-0.4s. Minutes later, I received a "Backend not found". I'm seeing TTFB of 2-4s right now.
Is there any workaround?
Appreciate any help.
